# Compare a pandas columns with a range of indices of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2    col3
 1        A       A
 2        A       A
 3        B       A
 4        A       B
 5        A       A
 6        C       A
 7        A       A
 8        A       C
 9        A       A
 10       A       A
 11       C       C
 12       A       A
 13       A       A
 14       A       A
 15       C       A
 16       A       A
 17       A       A
```

I want to create a function where if B or C is found in a same row in col1 and col2 **or** B or C of col1  present n rows above or below in col2, this will create another column a and mark as present.

for example if the function is  and if I put f(df,2,'B','C'), this will return,

df

```
df
col1    col2    col3      col4
 1        A       A        NA
 2        A       A        NA
 3        B       A       present
 4        A       B        NA
 5        A       A        NA
 6        C       A       present
 7        A       A        NA
 8        A       C        NA
 9        A       A        NA
 10       A       A        NA
 11       C       C        present
 12       A       A        NA
 13       A       A        NA
 14       A       A        NA
 15       C       A        NA
 16       A       A        NA
 17       A       A        NA
```

I could do it using a for loop, but the execution time will be huge, I am looking for some pandas shortcut / pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is compare both columns with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for membership and then check if N values above and below has at least one True values - first are created unique groups by index values with [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html), converting to `Series` by [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and forward anf back filling missing values for groups what is passed to [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `any`:

```
def f(df,N,a,b):

    m1 = df['col2'].isin([a,b])
    m2 = df['col3'].isin([a,b])
    g = df.index.where(m1).to_series().ffill(limit=N).bfill(limit=N).fillna(-1).values

    m3 = m2.groupby(g).transform('any')

    df['col4'] = np.where(m1 & m3, 'present', np.nan)
    return df

df = f(df,2,'B','C')
print (df)
    col1 col2 col3     col4
0      1    A    A      nan
1      2    A    A      nan
2      3    B    A  present
3      4    A    B      nan
4      5    A    A      nan
5      6    C    A  present
6      7    A    A      nan
7      8    A    C      nan
8      9    A    A      nan
9     10    A    A      nan
10    11    C    C  present
11    12    A    A      nan
12    13    A    A      nan
13    14    A    A      nan
14    15    C    A      nan
15    16    A    A      nan
16    17    A    A      nan
```